# How can I use ng-repeat to iterate through arrays associated using dynamic keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to use ng-repeat to iterate through an array of objects and use each objects ID to look up the data binded to a checklist model.
I have the following javascript object in a  project I'm working on:

```
{
diagnosis: {
            mainfractures: [
                        {
                            id: "metacarpal",
                            textinput_id: "metacarpal_text",
                            title: "5th Metacarpal",
                        },
                        {
                            id: "proximal_phalanx",
                            textinput_id: "proximal_phalanx_text",
                            title: "Proximal Phalanx",
                        },
                        {
                            id: "middle_phalanx",
                            textinput_id: "middle_phalanx_text",
                            title: "Middle Phalanx",
                        },
                        {
                            id: "distal_phalanx",
                            textinput_id: "distal_phalanx_text",
                            title: "Distal Phalanx",
                        },
                        {
                            id: "scaphoid_fracture",
                            textinput_id: "scaphoid_fracture_text",
                            title: "Scaphoid Fracture",
                        }
          ]
   }}
```

Here is what I have for my checklist model. As the user selects a checkbox, a value is binded to the array associated with that fracture.

```
$scope.checklists = {
                    "diagnosis": {
                         metacarpal: [],
                         proximal_phalanx: [],
                         middle_phalanx: [],
                         distal_phalanx: [],
                         scaphoid_fracture: []
                    }
                }
```

[Checklist Image Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TDUI.png)

Once a users makes a selection similar to the image above the the checklist model for metacarpal should look like this: metacarpal: ["head"]

What I'm trying to do is list each of the users selection in bulletpoint via fracture.id. I'm trying to accomplish it with this piece of code but it's only listed the fracture title so far. is it a problem with trying to interpolate fracture.id into ng-repeat?

```
<div ng-repeat="fracture in diagnosis.mainfractures">
          <div > <!--ng-if="checklists['diagnosis'][fracture.id] > 0"-->
            <h4>{{ fracture.title }}</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <ul type="disc">
                <li ng-repeat="selection in checklists['diagnosis'][fracture.id]">
                  &bull; {{ capitalize(selection) }}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I'm confused, according to your mainfractures dataset, there is no "head". Meaning checklists['diagnosis']['head'] would be undefined. You could potentially do something like checklists['diagnosis']['metacarpal']

Comment: head does not come up undefined because I did not paste in the full model. what I'm trying to do is iterate through of diagnosis properties and their corresponding arrays, then display each element. I'm trying to accomplish this with "fracture.id". Sorry, if came across unclear.

Comment: Check my answer. If the issue isn't due to syntax errors, then please update your question with the code that executes when you check a 'head' or 'neck'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your supplied code, I'd have to say your issue is actually due to JS syntax errors. You're missing commas after each object item and there is a random double quote here `scaphoid_fracture"[]`.

```
$scope.checklists = {
                "diagnosis": {
                     metacarpal: []
                     proximal_phalanx: []
                     middle_phalanx: []
                     distal_phalanx: []
                     scaphoid_fracture"[]
                }
            }
```

Here is a fully working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkskccxL/)

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted the code a bit:

- capitalize ->
  uppercase(https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/uppercase)
- some syntax errors

But seems that access by dynamic object key inside ng-repeat works pretty correct

https://jsbin.com/rodecosoyo/1/edit?html,js,output

Angular Application

```
var app = angular.module('arrayid', []);

app.controller('arrayContainerCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.diagnosis = {
    mainfractures: [{
      id: "metacarpal",
      textinput_id: "metacarpal_text",
      title: "5th Metacarpal",
    }, {
      id: "proximal_phalanx",
      textinput_id: "proximal_phalanx_text",
      title: "Proximal Phalanx",
    }, {
      id: "middle_phalanx",
      textinput_id: "middle_phalanx_text",
      title: "Middle Phalanx",
    }, {
      id: "distal_phalanx",
      textinput_id: "distal_phalanx_text",
      title: "Distal Phalanx",
    }, {
      id: "scaphoid_fracture",
      textinput_id: "scaphoid_fracture_text",
      title: "Scaphoid Fracture",
    }]
  };

  $scope.checklists = {
    "diagnosis": {
      metacarpal: ['1', '2'],
      proximal_phalanx: ['2', '3'],
      middle_phalanx: ['3'],
      distal_phalanx: ['4'],
      scaphoid_fracture: ['5']
    }
  };

});
```

Markup:

```
<body ng-app='arrayid' ng-controller='arrayContainerCtrl'>
  <div ng-repeat="fracture in diagnosis.mainfractures">
      <h4>{{ fracture.title }}</h4>
      <div class="row">
        <ul type="disc">
          <li ng-repeat="selection in checklists['diagnosis'][fracture.id]">
            &bull; {{ selection | uppercase }}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This shows how the ng-repeat could be used, but I don't think this actually satisfies his stated goal of displaying a users selections.